# how to execute padding and background CSS Properties in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css

```
.header 
{
    background:url(images/header.png);background-repeat:repeat-x 0 0;padding:29px 0 0 0; 
}
```

This code is not execute in Internet Explorer, Can you help me.?

Comment: It works [fine in this example](http://jsbin.com/xizica/1/edit). Make sure that you have the correct path to the png image. Tested all the way back to IE6.

Comment: [Here is a good guide for you](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Comment: I am using IE8, This code is execute in Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, and Safari, now i am again check perfectly cannot run in IE8.

Comment: Does [this example work in IE8 for you?](http://jsbin.com/xizica/1)

Comment: No Cannot work in IE8 only.

Comment: Do you [see the red image in this example in IE8?](http://jsbin.com/xizica/3/)

Comment: how to execute perfectly ? my IE version is **8**.0.7600.16385

Comment: no, i didn't see any red image. what is red image?

Comment: sorry, am seeing in this link http://jsbin.com/xizica/3/   ** background color is red and text is content** this is work in IE8 but i want backgroun image and padding.**

Comment: Then add padding like [this example](http://jsbin.com/xizica/4). The CSS is fine.

Comment: `**padding: 29px 0 0 0;**` but not work to me? you can use many .js(JavaScript) files in this link view-source:http://jsbin.com/xizica/4     but am using css only.

Comment: That will give you the same as: `padding-top: 20px;`. right,bottom and left padding is set at 0. Shorthand works like this: `padding: top-value right-value bottom-value left-value;`

Comment: <pre>`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Background Image &amp; Padding IE8</title>
<style>
.header 
{
  background:url(../brainbright/css/images/children2.png);
 padding: 20px 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
  content
 </div>
</body>
</html>`</pre>  This code is work perfectly in separate file but not run my project. but my project css is responsive.

Comment: `<style>
.header 
{
background:url(../brainbright/css/images/children2.png);padding: 20px 0 0;
}
</style><header class="header"></header>` but am using <header> html5 tag. how to rectify this error.

Comment: i think html5 tag is not working IE8. so that CSS property also not working.ex. **`<header class="example">`** class example css properties are not working in IE8.

Comment: OK, thats the problem. At the top of your CSS put this: `header { display: block; }`. This will cause IE8 to treat it like a div, essentially. At the moment, IE8 doesn't know what to do with it. You can repeat this for each HTML5 element that you use.

Comment: No, am execute `header { display:block; }` but not execute in IE8.

Comment: thanks for your information. any other info paste here.